# Desmos saying there are too many variables

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I wasn't sure if this is a Computational Science SE question or a Stack Overflow question but I think it's more of this one.

I wanted to make a graph where I can rotate a hyperbola (not parabola or ellipse) about any point, not just the origin on a Cartesian Plane. This is the equation:
$$\left(\frac{(y-k)\sin\theta-(x-h)\cos\theta}a\right)^2-\left(\frac{(y-k)\cos\theta-(x-h)\sin\theta}b\right)^2=1$$

But when I [plot this equation in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tugq3mntkz), it keeps saying *Too many variables. I don't know  what to do with this.* It seems like the $\sin$ and $\cos$ are causing it to say that because when I take it out, it doesn't say that anymore.

**Question:** Why is it saying that? How is the $\sin$ and $\cos$ causing it to say there are too many variables. Is my equation wrong or is it the graphing calculator itself that is at fault?

Comment: In your equation, what are the actual variables and what are parameters out of $x,y,a,k,b,h,\theta$?

Comment: @AntonMenshov a is the distance of the vertex to the origin, b is the distance from the vertex to the asymptote, h and k are the points of rotation, and theta is the angle of rotation.

Comment: In general, these types of questions are off-topic here. However, they also can be totally lost on SO and not receive any attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desmos seems to be picky about variable names.
The moment I renamed $\theta$ into $t$, the plotting started to work correctly.

[Desmos plot link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/footuuxlom)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much, sir. I was so fed up as to why it wasn't working while all I had to do was just rename $\theta$. Thanks.